# Custom bash prompt - cursor positioning issue

Tags: bash, prompt

I know there are many related questions, however I couldn't find any other way to get help on this problem:

On my CentOS VM I made a custom script for my bash prompt in `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh`

```
PS1="\n\e[0;97m\][\D{%d%m%y-%H%M}][\u@\h \W] \n\e[m\]\$ "
export PS1
```

My bash now looks like this:

[image: custom bash prompt]

However If I type a long command and if I want to get the cursor on the first position using CTRL-A this is what happens:

*Typed something long. I want to change something at the beginning of the line so I will press CTRL-A to get the cursor at the first position:*

[image: typing a long command]

*After pressing CTRL-A:*

[image]

Now if I try to delete the whole line with DEL or BACKSPACE this is the end result?

[image]

No matter how much I try to delete those 4 chars they always stay until I hit the ENTER key. Those last 4 chars are always displayed but it is like they don't exist.. I am free to type commands and they will be ignored:

[image]

At the last picture I successfully executed `cd /var` command and now the bash is like it is intended.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `\[` before each `\e`:

```
PS1="\n\[\e[0;97m\][\D{%d%m%y-%H%M}][\u@\h \W] \n\[\e[0m\]\$ "
```

Comment: `\[\e` is the first one and `\[\e` is near the end of that line? I don't see anywhere else..

Comment: @Spirit You need to use `\[` and `\]` in pairs.  Your original `PS1` had 2 unmatched `\]`s.  Find the difference carefully.